# Properly Configuring Kafka Connect S3 Sink TimeBasedPartitioner

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to use the TimeBasedPartitioner of the Confluent S3 sink. Here is my config:

```
{  
"name":"s3-sink",
"config":{  
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "file":"test.sink.txt",
    "topics":"xxxxx",
    "s3.region":"yyyyyy",
    "s3.bucket.name":"zzzzzzz",
    "s3.part.size":"5242880",
    "flush.size":"1000",
    "storage.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
    "schema.generator.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
    "timestamp.extractor":"Record",
    "timestamp.field":"local_timestamp",
    "path.format":"YYYY-MM-dd-HH",
    "partition.duration.ms":"3600000",
    "schema.compatibility":"NONE"
}
```

}

The data is binary and I use an avro scheme for it. I would want to use the actual record field "local_timestamp" which is a UNIX timestamp to partition the data, say into hourly files.

I start the connector with the usual REST API call

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @s3-config.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Unfortunately the data is not partitioned as I wish. I also tried to remove the flush size because this might interfere. But then I got the error

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nMissing required configuration \"flush.size\" which has no default value.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}%
```

Any idea how to properly set the TimeBasedPartioner? I could not find a working example.

Also how can one debug such a problem or gain further insight what the connector is actually doing?

Greatly appreciate any help or further suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed your amended configuration seems correct.

Specifically, setting `timestamp.extractor` to `RecordField` allows you to partition your files based on the timestamp field that your records have and which you identify by setting the property `timestamp.field`.

When instead one sets `timestamp.extractor=Record`, then a time-based partitioner will use the Kafka timestamp for each record.

Regarding `flush.size`, setting this property to a high value (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) will be practically synonymous to ignore it.

Finally, `schema.generator.class` is no longer required in the most recent versions of the connector.

Answer (score 7):

After studying the code at [TimeBasedPartitioner.java](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/partitioner/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/TimeBasedPartitioner.java) and the logs with

```
confluent log connect tail -f
```

I realized that both timezone and locale are mandatory, although this is not specified as such in the [Confluent S3 Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-storage-cloud/kafka-connect-s3/docs/configuration_options.html) documentation. The following config fields solve the problem and let me upload the records properly partitioned to S3 buckets:

```
"flush.size": "10000",
"storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
"format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
"schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
"partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
"path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
"locale": "US",
"timezone": "UTC",
"partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
"timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
"timestamp.field": "local_timestamp",
```

Note two more things: First a value for flush.size is also necessary, files are partitioned eventually into smaller chunks, not larger than specified by flush.size. Second, the path.format is better selected as displayed above so a proper tree structure is generated.

I am still not 100% sure if really the record field **local_timestamp** is used to partition the records.

Any comments or improvements are greatly welcome.

Comment: did the above work? I get `PartitionException: Error encoding partition` which probably means (per the code that you linked above) my messages (Avro)  were not deserialized correctly. Did you use schema registry?

Comment: Yes I used schema registry and the above code worked. I guess without schema registry it cannot work

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had to also specify `"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"` and `"value.converter.schema.registry.url": <my_schema_registry-url>` to make it work. By default, the converter was set to `ByteArrayConverter`. So, had to override it.

Comment: Oh, yes that is needed, otherwise now way to understand the data structure.